# Puppet Plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, puppet

How to integrate Jenkins with Puppet?

As of now i am integrating Jenkins with Puppet. But We dont know which  puppet plugin will support for jenkins. Can you please help on us.

Comment: What do you expect the setup to do, what are the actual steps you are trying to perform, and in what way do they fail?

Comment: In Jenkins how to integrate Puppet. and in jenkins after buliding we got a .war file. Now i want to know how to place the war on puppet Module path. We installed puppet plugin in jenkins but how to use.What plug-ins has to install on Jenkins to integrate Puppet.Master. Can you please help us on this.

Comment: Please update the question so that the questions in the first comment are answered. You just repeated the original question in the comment. This is too broad a question to answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If you simply want to deploy the manifests, there is no need for a puppet plugin. You could use the [Publish over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) plugin or something that let you push your code to the puppet master. 
To actually execute puppet commands a generic job configuration would be fine.
If you are looking for a full chain of source control, tests and deployment for your manifests, you should take a look at [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) and how to integrate it with Jenkins using the Gerrit Trigger plugin

Comment: In Jenkins how to integrate Puppet. and in jenkins after buliding we got a .war file. Now i want to know how to place the war on puppet Module path. We installed puppet plugin in jenkins but how to use.What plug-ins has to install on Jenkins to integrate Puppet.Master. Can you please help us on this.